# Heroku; “No such process type web defined in Procfile” error

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to do

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

However I'm getting the error

```
No such process type web defined in Procfile.
```

I'm following this tutorial [Real Time chat with Node js](http://tutorialzine.com/2014/03/nodejs-private-webchat/#comment-146377) and I'm not able do "heroku open" at the end; the error I received was [H14](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes) so I'm trying to scale my web dynos to 1. I've a Procfile.txt and inside of it has

```
web: node app.js
```

I've read that I would need to make sure the "P" is capitalized and everything spell correctly which I have. So I'm not sure why I still can't scale my web dynos to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should just be `Procfile` - no extension. You need to drop the `.txt`.

`mv Procfile.txt Procfile` should fix it up for you (if you're on *nix).

Comment: Kinda confused, so it would be mkdir Procfile?

Comment: It's not a folder, it's a file - just a file without an extension. To create it, you can `touch Procfile`. Or with the contents you want, you can `echo 'web: node app.js' > Procfile`. Or you can simply rename the one you have with `mv`, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: How would I do it if I'm on windows working in CMD? The same way?

Comment: Windows command line is admittedly my Achilles heel, but I believe `echo web: node app.js > Procfile` should work fine.