# Heroku Procfile not seeing my web: definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dyno

I am trying to add a dyno to my Rail app on Heroku.  I added the following to my Procfile:

```
web: dyno:type web=1 --app=webruin-
```

I have tried it with `Web:` and `web:`.

When I run `heroku dyno:type web=1 --app webruin-`, I get:

```
Resizing and restarting the specified dynos... failed
!    No such process type web defined in Procfile.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers,

Tim

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051903/heroku-no-such-process-type-web-defined-in-procfile-error ?

Comment: My Procfile does not have an extension.  But thanks :)